# Can I restore my wiped out Religion in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

I was late to the religion party, so my neighbour snuck in and converted all my cities to his religion. Now I seem to be unable get my own religion back.

In the previous edition, I could use a Great Prophet, or just rely on my Holy City's strong pressure, but neither of these options seems to be available in Civ 6 (I have no Great Prophets available under Great People, it seems like they are only used to found a religion now?).

I have thousands of stored faith, but any unit I buy will have the dominant religion (my neighbour's).

I've tried looking through the civilopedia, to no avail.

Has anyone found a way of clawing back your own religion from destruction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you have lost the religious war, friend.

You are correct about Great Prophets; there are indeed a limited quantity of them. In my 6-player game on Prince difficulty, there were 4 Great Prophets. I believe you are also correct in saying they are used strictly for founding a Religion. I did not notice any other options for that unit during my game.

As you have mentioned, buying units with faith corresponds to the dominant religion in that city. If you still have citizens following your religion, there may be some small hope for the pressure to bubble and your religion to become dominant again, but that is unlikely at best. Cities spread pressure based on how many followers are in that city; the dominant religion will almost always be emitting the most pressure. If you chose traits that increase pressure in some way, your religion might resurface. Otherwise, I believe it has been lost to the waves of time.

DISCLAIMER: This game is a new release, and this evidence is almost all anecdotal from gameplay experience.

Comment: That's pretty much what I though too. Accepting this pending someone discovering something we may have missed.

Comment: Does this mean its a race to convert the enemies cities with religous units. Once the majority they will start spreading your religion and cannot remove the religious buildings they build that now that assist your victory?

Comment: Maybe? Nothing will force them to keep spreading your religion once converted. Also religious units can now fight against other religious units via "religious battle", so you can actually defend against enemy religions more than before.

Comment: If Jerusalem is in the game, you can possibly "resurrect" your religion by becoming suzerain of that city; this automatically causes Jerusalem to become your founded religion and spread it as though it were the holy city. You probably have to get a little lucky to get your religion to spread past Jerusalem though.

Comment: If you clear your holy city of any hostile religions, you can also resurrect your religion by building the Mahabodhi Temple wonder. This wonder grants you two apostles of your religion.

Answer (score 8):

You actually might still have a chance. Killing religious units reduces that religion in a radius by up to 250. So just declare war on who ever is the majority and run over all the missionaries and apostles with horseman.

Comment: I thought that only applied if they lost a religious combat, not a normal combat. And since my religion is wiped out, I can't fight them with missionaries etc.

Comment: You can definitely trigger this effect by killing an enemy religious unit with one of your own military units, so in theory this approach could work. Presumably though you'd need the enemy civ to spam you with enough religious units first.

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct, only just managed to confirm this for myself today.

Comment: I believe winning in theological combat both decreases theirs and increases yours, while using a military unit just decreases theirs.